# zsh: command not found: duarouter to create a rou.xml file

Tags: sumo

I'm using sumo in macOS. I'm trying to create a duarouter by calling the following command after creating a random trips for a given network:

```
duarouter -n ~/SUMOTutorials/sumotest.net.xml --route-files ~/SUMOTutorials/sumotest.trips.xml -o ~/SUMOTutorials/sumotest.rou.xml --ignore-errors
```

However I just get the error:

> zsh: command not found: duarouter

I see in sumo directory there is duarouter of kind Unix executable file in sumo/bin and sumo/tests and in I run the above command when I'm in each of those directory but I just get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Because the type is Unix executable file, we have to write the following in the directory where it is:

```
./duarouter -n ~/SUMOTutorials/sumotest.net.xml --route-files ~/SUMOTutorials/sumotest.trips.xml -o ~/SUMOTutorials/sumotest.rou.xml --ignore-errors.
```